# What does the notation $f(x) = max (1-t \mid, 0)$ mean?

Tags: functions, notation

I don't understand that vertical bar?

Comment: Me neither... where does this vertical bar come from? Perhaps it is a typographical mistake only

Comment: I'm asked to find the fourier-transform of that function. Might as well be a typo indeed.

Comment: It most likely is a typo of $\max(1-t,0)$ because $\max(|1-t|,0)=|1-t|$.